# How to router.navigate to a route with an id placeholder inmidst the route url

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a route url like:

```js
    /departments/:id/employees/assign'
```

When I navigate to the above url:

```js
    this._router.navigate(['/departments/:id/employees/assign', id]);
```

Then angular is always appending the passed id to the end of the url, but that is not what I want.

When I try this

```js
    this._router.navigate(['/departments/:id/employees/assign', {id: id}]);
```

I get this url in the browser:

```js
    http://localhost:4200/departments/%3Aid/employees/assign;id=1
```

I want the url to be in the browser: `/departments/1/employees/assign`

What do I have to change?

Comment: Have you tried using a template literal?  something like `[\`/departments/${id}/employees/assign\`]`

Comment: Thanks, the backticks made my nice url working! Please make a solution of it! So you see asp.net as dark age ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use template literals to form dynamic urls like this:

```
[`/departments/${id}/employees/assign`]
```

Answer (score 5):

According to doc https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html, you should choose either to user navigateByUrl :

> router.navigateByUrl("/departments/:id/employees/assign");

or split the components of the url in parts :

> router.navigate(['departments', 1, 'employees', assign], {relativeTo: route});

Comment: This should be the answer. This is the more correct way to do it.